# How do prevent TextWrangler save alert (This file appears to have been modified) on Mac?

Tags: macos, text, software-distribution, textwrangler

Whenever I save a file in TextWrangler, I keep getting a popup alert with the text:

"The file at sample.sh may have been changed on disk by another application. If so, saving this document may cause data loss. Are you sure you wish to proceed?"

This is the popup itself*:

[image]

<sub>*Image taken on macOS 10.13.6.</sub>

What is causing this and how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a workaround: Turn off "Automatically refresh documents as they change on disk" in Preferences->Application.

Answer (score 6):

It could be an OS related issue - TextWrangler is no longer supported on macOS 10.13. [according to Rich Siegel of Bare Bones Software, Inc.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bbedit/1o90wcjRH5c):

*The version of BBEdit you're (both) using is out of date, and is 
not supported on macOS 10.13.*

TextWrangler is BBEdit now.

Comment: You don't have to pay for it. BBEdit will disable some advanced features after the trial period ends, but will continue working.

Answer (score 2):

TextWrangler was an all-purpose text and code editor for macOS, based on the same award-winning technology and user interface as BBEdit, our leading professional HTML and text editor.

TextWrangler is now part of BBEdit. We have sunsetted TextWrangler, and we encourage anyone not already using TextWrangler to download and use BBEdit instead.

If you are an existing TextWrangler customer, it’s time to switch to BBEdit. We promise that you will feel right at home, because the two products are identical in every way that you’re used to. And you still don’t have to pay anything, unless you want to support us by buying a license.

TextWrangler is not compatible with macOS 10.13 (High Sierra). Please install and use BBEdit instead.

https://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/

Comment: Upvote this comment if you have tried BBEdit and prefer Textwrangler!